# C# transparent buttons

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to create a button that has an image on it with a hole in the middle,
thus making the hole transparent?
and when another image moves behind the button you see it through the hole?

Comment: yonatan, please accept the answers to more of your questions.

Comment: You might as well consider this not possible in WinForms. If you feel you absolutely need this kind of eye candy, switch to WPF if you're not using it already.

Comment: C# doesn't have buttons. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your best bet is to use WPF in this case, XAML has a bunch of nice ways of doing just that.  You can use gradient stops in a gradient brush, for example, to set color and transparency.

Comment: Agree, the OP probably wants the hole to be circular, RadialGrandientBrush would be fine for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put two images on the button. The round one should be the non visible one.

see also: 
[Why some controls has both BackgroundImage and Image property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634904/why-some-controls-has-both-backgroundimage-and-image-property)

Comment: What do you mean by "two images"? How do you put two images on a button?

Comment: In winForms you have a backgroundImage and a (foreGround)Image. Anyway, the BackColor and ForeColor can be set to Transparent.