# Why some controls has both BackgroundImage and Image property?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

Why some controls like `Button` or `PictureBox` has both `BackgroundImage` and `Image` property?

why in case of button both of them is needed?
or why in picturebox backgroundimage should be available?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the two?

Comment: @matt: yes, why in case of button both of them is needed?

Comment: @matt: or why in picturebox backgroundimage should be available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BackgroundImage` is inherited from `Control`.

`Image`, in the case of `Button` is inherited from `ButtonBase`.

---

In general, the [`BackgroundImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx) is:

> An Image that represents the image to display in the background of the control.

And the `Image` will be the one that is **on** the control.

---

Why do you need the two?

- Because you may have margins around a control where you want the background image to show on them.
- Because sometimes you may use transparencies on the `Image` and want the background image to show through.

Answer (score 3):

This is largely because it is there anyway.  It gets inherited from the Control class, no extra work is needed to make it functional.  In fact, extra work is needed to *hide* it, required for native Windows controls that don't support a background image.  Like TreeView:

```
public class TreeView : Control
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    public override Image BackgroundImage
    {
       // etc..
    }
// etc..
}
```

Note the override keyword and the attributes required to hide it in both the property grid and the editor.  Extra work to stop it from working.